# elasticsearch returns "Unassigned"

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, unassigned-variable

When I index any document in elasticsearch, I always find out that the data is Unassigned. When I try to search, sort, delete or update any data it data, it works perfectly.

[image: elasticsearch data using head plugin]

The Cluster health is yellow:

[image]

Here is the index metadata:

```
{
"state": "open",
"settings": {
"index": {
"creation_date": "1435151717012",
"number_of_shards": "5",
"uuid": "ixYnG8_ESa-b7ZHWrnFqRw",
"version": {
"created": "1060099"
},
"number_of_replicas": "1"
}
},
"mappings": { "hello": { ....... }},
"aliases": [ ]
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, so the data is "Unassigned". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where does the first screenshot come from? Is it generated by a bundle?

Comment: how many nodes in the cluster ? it could be that you just have a single node that is up and the setting says 1 replica resulting in it being unassigned

Comment: @A.L yes it is generated from a bundle ...

Comment: @keety there are 5 nodes in the cluster ...

Comment: @Christofer: what bundle?

Comment: Inside the symfony named MyDataBundle ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply the following setting to enable the shard allocation:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/{index}/_settings' -d '{"index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": false}'
```